# Does anyone know what 'Milch kaputt 3 papier' means

Tags: meaning

"[Milch Kaputt 3 Papier](https://vimeo.com/215474836)" is the title of a German short film.
The synopsis given [here](https://www.dffb.de/films/milch-kaputt-3-papier/) just says

> Die Milch ist alle. Etwas liegt in der Luft. Bunte Vögel im Fernseher.

**What does the title mean?**

I have been looking in several dictionaries, for example:
https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Redewendungen#M

Added 2022 jan 30th

I was looking for the same.
I often heard my turkish mates using this words but I never asked them about the meaning.
It seems it is something translated from turkish language to German language that has lost its meaning in translation.

Comment: this means nothing... please add some context where you THINK this comes from: This is absolute gibberish / nonsense, just 3 random words and one number... means the same in english: "Milk broken 3 paper"... nothing...

Comment: That is impossible to say without knowing the context. It looks like a meaningless jumble of words.

Comment: ok, just Googled... seems to be a title of a German comedy... still the answer stays the same: It means nothing... "Ist das Kunst, oder kann das weg?"

Comment: Seems to be the title of a short film: https://g.co/kgs/fNg5PR

Comment: @Arsak: If Alex did the work you did, then I would now upvote... We can only guess that this is the question he really wanted to ask, but we cannot know... If the community fixes lacy worded zero effort posts then OP will never learn how to ask valid und valuable questions by themselves... therefor: I keep my downvote until Alex himselve puts some work into this post...

Comment: @TorstenLink I wouldn't have done this for a regular user. But I think it's more encouraging for new users to *show* them what we expect (not only tell and downvote/close). And you're right, we can not be 100% certain that this is what Alex wanted to know, but the word combination is so odd and specific that I was confident enough to edit this in. And if it's not what they wanted, Alex can still change the given context.

Comment: Title #3 subtitle

Answer (score 3):

These 4 words do not have any meaning in that context. They are just random words probably taken from one or more senseless conversations within the movie.

Most probably you can see that as "artistic freedom".

If might be, that the "inner sense" of these words is explained in the movie, but it does not have to be necessarily.

I tried to find a comment from the director or the writers of the movie, but could not find anything...